# parallelism algorithm C++?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

I am looking for a way to find the largest number in an unsorted array that contains distinct integers with span of (log n). 
I have thought of divide and conquer approach but it seems that would be (log^2 n)

any suggestions?

Comment: Any chance you can use [CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/how-to-cuda-c-cpp)? :3

Comment: no .. i can use things like running many threads in parallel, divide and conquer, Map, Reduce or Filter/Pack....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My easiest-to-implement guess would be tying something like `std::reduce` with paralellism as execution policy with `std::max` as binary operation. It requires `c++17` support though.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce